# Problem with $ sign in temporary function parameter

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, parameters, arguments

I am having a problem with $ sign in the name of a parameter to a temporary function. The functions I have should compute the angular sum (or turning angle) for some expression generated by function `fMakeExpr[]`, which here is just a simplified version of the complex sine expression generated in the actual code. The angular sum is then computed by the integral in function `fSum[]` and returned to the calling function. The wrapper `fSumForSine[]` take as parameter an integer > 0 which determines the particular sine function generated, calls on `fMakeExpr[]` to generate the sine expression, and then calls on `fSum[]` to do the computation and returns the numeric result.

The problem I have is the parameter name for the temporary expression `f[x_ ]`, which Mathematica changes into `f[x$_ ]` in order to make it unique, but which is not recognized by the integral in `fSum[]`. If in `fSumForSine[]` the parameter ***n*** in the the line `f[x_] := Evaluate[fMakeExpr[n]];` is replaced by a constant, so the line instead is: `f[x_] := Evaluate[fMakeExpr[1]];` , then the param to the temporary function remains `[x_ ]` and everything works as it should. It also works if I with param as ***n*** call the functions directly from input line in the notebook, se more on that after the code below.

This is my code:

```
fMakeExpr[n_ ?NumericQ] := Module[{strBase, strSine, tmp},
   strBase := "(Sqrt[§] Sin[x]) + ((Sqrt[§+1]-1) Sin[§ x])";  (* 
   Example pattern for complex sine *)
   strSine := StringReplace[strBase, "§" -> ToString[n]];
   tmp := Evaluate[ToExpression[StringJoin[strSine]]];
   Return[Evaluate[ToExpression[ToString[tmp, InputForm]]]];
   ];

ClearAll[fSum];
fSum[f_ , from_ ?NumericQ, to_ ?NumericQ, dbg_ ] := (
   If[(dbg == True), (
     Print["fSum:f = ", Definition[f]];
     Print["fSum:ArcTan[f'[x]] = ", ArcTan[f'[x]]];
     Print["fSum:D[ArcTan[f'[x]],x] = ", D[ArcTan[f'[x]], x]];)
    ];
   Return[NIntegrate[Abs[D[ArcTan[f'[x]], x]], {x, from, to}]];
   );

ClearAll[fSumForSine];
fSumForSine[n_ ?NumericQ, dbg_ ] := Module[{f},
   f[x_] := Evaluate[fMakeExpr[n]];  (*<<< Param n = problem, constant = OK *)
   If[(dbg == True), Print["fSumForSine:f = ", Definition[f]]];
   Return[fSum[f, 0, 2 π, dbg]];
   ];
```

You can see the problem by executing this in the notebook (param should be ***n***):

**fSumForSine[1, False]**

You should get an error message and no value for angular sum. You can se the problem by activating debug printouts, like this:

**fSumForSine[1, True]**

Note the parameter name `[x_ ]` has been changed to `[x$_ ]`, and that is what seems to cause the problems later on in the integral.
Change the parameter ***n*** in the line to a constant ***1*** like I described above the code and see the difference and that it now works.

It also works, **with** param as ***n***, if I execute the calls directly from the notebook input line like this:

**f[x_] = fMakeExpr[1]**

**fSum[f, 0 , 2 π, False]**

I really hope someone can help me fix this problem, because I have been banging my head against this for days now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `x` to `fMakeExpr` and use it to replace a dummy variable in your string.

```
fMakeExpr[n_?NumericQ, x_] := 
  Module[{strBase, strSine, tmp}, 
   strBase := "(Sqrt[§] Sin[xx]) + ((Sqrt[§+1]-1) Sin[§ xx])"; 
   strSine := StringReplace[strBase, "§" -> ToString[n]];
   tmp = ToExpression[StringJoin[strSine]] /. xx -> x;
   ToExpression[ToString[tmp, InputForm]]];

fSumForSine[n_?NumericQ, dbg_] := 
  Module[{f}, f[x_] := Evaluate[fMakeExpr[n, x]];
   If[(dbg == True), Print["fSumForSine:f = ", Definition[f]]];
   fSum[f, 0, 2 \[Pi], dbg]];

fSumForSine[1, False]
 (* 3.82127 *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much MelaGo, that was the right medicine! I would never have been able to come up with that solution to the problem myself. I think I understand what it does: by forcing MMA to replace the xx with x, MMA appends a $ to indicate it should  at final evaluation be substituted with the variable used at that time, which is x. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than work with symbolic "function bodies", maybe you could just work with `Function`.

```
fMakeFn[n_?NumericQ] := Function[x, (Sqrt[n]  Sin[x]) + ((Sqrt[n + 1] - 1)  Sin[n  x])];
fSumForSineNew[n_?NumericQ, dbg_] := fSum[fMakeFn[n], 0, 2  \[Pi], dbg];

fSumForSineNew[1, False]
(* 3.82127 *)
```

Comment: Thank you lericr for that elegant construct. I could only make it work with a hardcoded expression like in your example, not sure why. Therefore, I have combined it with the solution provided by MelaGo above. Together these solutions finally made my code work